# Какие адреса из подсети 172.16.10.0 c длиной маски 26 можно использовать для адресации?

Tags: безопасность

Дана подсеть 172.16.10.0 c длиной маски 26. Какие адреса из этой подсети можно использовать для адресации?

Не могли бы вы в дополнение к ответу описать почему именно ЭТИ адреса можно использовать для адресации?

Comment: 172.16.10.0 - 172.16.10.63 см. https://infocisco.ru/cisco_formula_subnetting.html  , причем 63 - широковещательный

Comment: Вот здесь достаточно хорошая иллюстрация что и почему? https://ip-calculator.ru/#!ip=172.16.10.0/26

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать адреса со 172.16.10.0 по 172.16.10.63. Потому что именно эти адреса входят в подсеть 172.16.10.0/26. Другие адреса в эту подсеть не входят. При наложении маски подсети на адрес подсети будет видно, какие биты адреса подсети относятся к адресу подсети, а какие к адресу хоста в подсети.

Адрес 172.16.10.0 при этом является адресом самой подсети, адрес 172.16.10.63 - широковещательный адрес подсети, назначать эти два адреса машинам в этой подсети нельзя. Остальные адреса диапазона доступны для назначения машинам в этой подсети.